# Allowing just for select a option in select box MULTIPLE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can allowing that select just a "OPTION" in select box "MULTIPLE" no more, by jquery or ... ?

(You while keep "Ctrl+right click" in selectbox "MULTIPLE" you can select several option in select box "MULTIPLE" i don't want this)

I want style select box as multiple but it select just a option.

```
<SELECT NAME=sections MULTIPLE>
    <OPTION>Web Authoring Reference</OPTION>
    <OPTION>FAQ Archives</OPTION>
    <OPTION>Design Elements</OPTION>
    <OPTION>Tools</OPTION>
    <OPTION>Feature Article</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: Im sorry but I don't really get your question ? Do you want do select MULTIPLE options or do you want to select SINGLE options ? <br/>
Maybe you could check this website out: http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/html/form-combobox.php IF you want that only ONE Option can be selected than simply remove the MULTIPLE out of the select TAG !

Comment: Remove the word "multiple" and it will become a standard dropdown menu, which allows only one value to be selected. This is the correct user interface for picking a single value from a list. Trying to hack a multiple-select list to only allow picking one value, which it sounds like you're implying, may be possible but would be strongly discouraged and confusing for users.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: I'm not sure to what you're asking here? But if you want to select only one item why not remove the multiple attribute?

Comment: I want style select box as multiple but it select just a option. How is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick

```
<SELECT NAME=sections size=5 >
   <OPTION>Web Authoring Reference</OPTION>
   <OPTION>FAQ Archives</OPTION>
   <OPTION>Design Elements</OPTION>
   <OPTION>Tools</OPTION>
   <OPTION>Feature Article</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: no it is only the number of element that is shown, You could have an 100 options the first 5 would be display then the rest would be hidden in the overflow.